# what is RHS vector

Tags: java, apache, matrix

please I am trying to understand matrix computation. 
and my question may seem simple but please need an answer
can some briefly explain to me what is an RHS vector.
I often see it used in the Apache commons math library
 for example i got this from a stackoverflow page:

```
public class LinearAlgebraDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double [][] values = {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 4, -3}, {3, 6, -5}};
        double [] rhs = { 9, 1, 0 }; /* RHS Vector */

        RealMatrix a = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(values);

        DecompositionSolver solver = new LUDecompositionImpl(a).getSolver();

        RealVector b = new ArrayRealVector(rhs);
        RealVector x = solver.solve(b);

        RealVector residual = a.operate(x).subtract(b);
        double rnorm = residual.getLInfNorm();

    }
}
```

can someone explain this code to me and especially the RHS vector and its purpose.
thank you very much.

Comment: @GregHewgill post as an answer so I may upvote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You matrix equation looks like this:

```
Ax = b
```

where `A` is a matrix with m rows and n columns, `x` is a column vector of `m` unknowns, and `b` is another column vector (aka The Right-Hand Side) of `m` known values.  It's on the right hand side of the equals sign - hence the name.

If I gave you a simple equation with two numbers and an unknown value x, you'd know exactly how to solve it:

```
Ax = b -> x = b/A
```

Think of this as solving for x by multiplying both sides of the equation by the inverse of A.

In this case it's more complicated, because dividing by a matrix means inverting it.

You're not going to invert the matrix; you're going to create something called an LU decomposition of the matrix A.  You should read about what that is and why it's better than calculating a full inverse if you're interested.

Comment: Neat answer, could you clarify if this is the same than Multivariate regression ? I do not see the difference.

Comment: No, this is more likely to be something like a finite element analysis than a multivariate regression.  It's a square matrix.  A multivariate regression would have more rows than columns.  It would be expressed as conjugate gradient or A(transpose)*A = A(transpose)*b.  You can do LU decomposition on the latter.  Conjugate gradient formulations are iterative and don't require LU decomposition.

Comment: I dont see anywhere that RHS involves a square matrix and neither does MV regression

Comment: No, b on the RHS is a an n x 1 vector.  The m x n matrix A on the left hand side is square if you apply LU decomposition.  If m > n, you can either premultiply by the transpose and use LU decomposition to solve OR use conjugate gradient.  If m < n, SVD is appropriate. Multi-variate regress is certainly not square, but I already pointed that out.

Answer (score 2):

RHS is a common mathematical abbreviation for "right hand side". Here it appears that you are solving a system of linear equations `Ax = b` where `A` is an n x n matrix and `x` and `b` are n-dimensional column vectors. If you don't understand this terminology, then I suggest you study up on linear algebra.

As for the code, `rhs` is an array which is used to initialize the elements of the vector `b`. Similarly, the 2D array `values` is used to initialize the elements of the matrix `A` (actually a reference variable named `a`).